# Querying the Sqlite database for a user with username "x" using the standard django.contrib.auth.models.User model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to wrap my head around an issue I'm having.

I want to present the users with a page in which they can look up a user by entering his username.

Yet I can't wrap my head around how to do this. Do I provide a function in my view in which a query is executed that retrieves a user from the database? For example retrieve his username or id and go to his profile page? I can't seem to grasp how to do this, I have been looking for examples on this but I can't find anything so I hope someone here can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at the simplest level you would have a view that accepts a form submission which takes the value of the field and does something like `User.objects.get(username=my_variable)` and returns the results, if any. You should wrap the call in a `try`/ `except` block so your view doesn't blow up if no such user exists with that username. Django provides a [shortcut function for doing just this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), so instead of the line above you could do `user = get_object_or_404(User, username=my_variable)`. Your whole view would look something like

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def username_search(request):
  # if there are any form values sent in a GET
  if request.GET:
    my_variable = request.GET.get('username', '')
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=my_variable)
  else:
    user = None
  return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'user': user}
```

In reality you might also create a Django [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) to do some validation on the submissions and make it easier to render your form.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your comment. I have accepted it as the correct answer since it answers my initial question. However, I might have asked the question too simply. If you will, in the comments I will try to explain the situation and what I am trying to do.

A page in which a user can look for users - but for each user he selects, the form is cleared so he can look for other users too and then when he submits the form, all the selected users are passed to the next page.


How would one try to accomplish this?